# DocuSign REST API Service Reference C#

Tags: rest, docusignapi

I am trying to add service reference to Visual Studio for REST API.
The demo URL given to me by a DocuSign support engineer is as below.

https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2

But when I try to add it, I get the following error.

Do I need to add anything to web.config? Thanks in advance. I already have details related to SOAP in web.config. I added a second API URL string.

The document at the url https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2 was not recognized as a known document type.
The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:
- Report from 'XML Schema' is 'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.'.
- Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.'.
- Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'There is an error in XML document (1, 1).'.
  - Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2'.
There was no endpoint listening at https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2 that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the open source DocuSign NuGet package if you're using .NET / Visual Studio:
https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client

You can install it in seconds from the Tools menu and it will install the dependencies and references for your project automatically, then you can add your `using` statements in your code.

To get started follow the [README](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/README.md).